# Eclipse:Creating dynamic web project programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried creating dynamic web project by first creating java project through IProject and then converting it into dynamic web project by using IFacetedProject but only static project is getting created...here is the code which i have done...pls help me out with this..thanks in advance.

```
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IProject project = root.getProject("TESTJDT");

        try
        {
            project.create(null);
            project.open(null);
            IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
            description.setNatureIds(new String[] { JavaCore.NATURE_ID });
            project.setDescription(description, null);
            IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);

            IClasspathEntry[] buildPath = {
            JavaCore.newSourceEntry(project.getFullPath().append("src")),
            JavaRuntime.getDefaultJREContainerEntry() };

            javaProject.setRawClasspath(buildPath,project.getFullPath().append(
            "bin"), null);

            IFolder folder = project.getFolder("src");
            folder.create(true, true, null);

            IPackageFragmentRoot srcFolder = javaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot(folder);

            IPackageFragment fragment = srcFolder.createPackageFragment("com.programcreek", true, null);

            String str = "package com.programcreek;" + "\n"
            + "public class Test  {" + "\n" + " private String name;"+ "\n" + "}";

            ICompilationUnit cu = fragment.createCompilationUnit("Test.java", str,false, null);


            IType type = cu.getType("Test");

            type.createField("private String age;", null, true, null);

            IFacetedProject facetedProject =
                ProjectFacetsManager.create(project, true, null);
            IProjectDescription description1 = project.getDescription();
            description1.setNatureIds(new String[]
        {"org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature",
        "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature",
        "org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature",
        "org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature",
        "org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature"});

            project.setDescription(description1, null);
            IProjectFacet wstWebFacet = ProjectFacetsManager.getProjectFacet
                (IModuleConstants.WST_WEB_MODULE);
            facetedProject.installProjectFacet
                (wstWebFacet.getDefaultVersion(), null, null);
```

Comment: just a hack if the API is restrictive here: you could look into '.project' of an existing dynamic web project, and manually extend the new project with java nature programmatically by those lines, once created. The workspace will anticipate this when updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
public static IProject getWebDataModel(String projName, boolean createDD) throws ExecutionException{
    IDataModel dm = DataModelFactory.createDataModel(new SimpleWebFacetProjectCreationDataModelProvider());
    dm.setProperty(IFacetProjectCreationDataModelProperties.FACET_PROJECT_NAME, projName);

    FacetDataModelMap facetMap = (FacetDataModelMap) dm.getProperty(IFacetProjectCreationDataModelProperties.FACET_DM_MAP);
    IDataModel facetModel = facetMap.getFacetDataModel(IJ2EEFacetConstants.DYNAMIC_WEB);
    facetModel.setProperty(IFacetDataModelProperties.FACET_VERSION, JavaEEFacetConstants.WEB_25);

    facetModel.setBooleanProperty(IJ2EEFacetInstallDataModelProperties.GENERATE_DD, createDD);
    IDataModel javaFacetModel = facetMap.getFacetDataModel(IJ2EEFacetConstants.JAVA);
    javaFacetModel.setProperty(IFacetDataModelProperties.FACET_VERSION, JavaEEFacetConstants.JAVA_5);

    IStatus st = dm.getDefaultOperation().execute(new NullProgressMonitor(), null);
    return st.isOK() ? ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(projName) : null;
}
```

You also can use restricted class `WebFacetProjectCreationDataModelProvider` instead of `SimpleWebFacetProjectCreationDataModelProvider` if you don't mind to use non-public API.